# Troubles with implementing IClientValidatable- GetClientValidationRules never fires

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a custom validator for my MVC4 application. To keep things simple and focus on the purpose of this question let's say that I'm reimplementing the `RequiredAttribute` class's server and client side validation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MyRequiredAttribute: ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute() : base("The {0} field is required.")
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()));
    }
}
```

To test this I have a very simple controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyThing {Value = "whatever"});
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyThing thing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Content("Good choice!");
        }
        return View(thing);
    }
}
```

and a very simple model:

```
public class MyThing
{
    [MyRequired]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

and finally the Index View:

```
@model MyThing

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithAllTheAppropriateValidationScripts.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm()){
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll note that I have `Value` which is decorated with the custom `MyRequiredAttribute` and `OtherValue` which is decorated with the standard `RequiredAttribute`.

Both of these work beautifully server-side and return the appropriate validation messages on postback, but only the standard `RequiredAttribute` works on the client side. Since I'm using a `ModelClientValidationRequiredRule` instead of a `ModelClientValidationRule` with a custom `ValidationType` property I'm assuming that no custom clientside validation rules need to be defined, but I don't know that for sure because I haven't been able to get that far. The debugger never breaks inside of the `GetClientValidationRules` method and the input html element generated for the `Value` property on my model does not have the `data-val-required` and `data-val` attributes as does the `OtherValue` field, which I'm assuming is what the `GetClientValidationRules` method is responsible for doing.

I must be missing something simple here... what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be user error, but I'll post the solution anyway in hopes that it helps someone else with a similar problem down the road.

The code in the original question is in a separate assembly from the MVC project that uses it. The MVC project had recently been upgraded from MVC3 to MVC4. I had [followed the instructions provided by Microsoft on upgrading](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806), or so I thought. I missed one piece in the web.config:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This tells the MVC project how to play nice with assemblies on which it depends that were compiled with a reference to an earlier version of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. After upgrading my MVC project it referenced `System.Web.Mvc` v4 and my "Common" project (where the extended `ValidatorAttribute` implementing `IClientValidatable` lived) referenced v3. The configuration above should have been updated with the upgrade but it got missed. The issue did not manifest in any other way except for the client-side validation issue outlined in the original question.

The offending line here was

```
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
```

which should have been

```
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
```

which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Global.asax:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyRequiredAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

This should solve your client-side validation issue.

Comment: This is actually combining two different approaches to creating custom validation attributes as outlined [here](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/custom-unobstrusive-jquery-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider/) and [here](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/custom-unobstrusive-jquery-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/). I'm using the IClientValidatable approach in the code I provided. Simply adding the line of code you provided isn't sufficient.